# Adding values from different records

Tags: sql

From the below table I want to add 2 values from the same records and one value from different record, that are (extraaamt from the first record)+(trnamt from the second record)

```
 5140560000001183   1016.00     0.00    2014-05-23  R       0.00    1017    13
 5140560000001183   1016.00     0.00    2014-05-24  N       30.00   1017    0




carno               emi         recamt  lastrecdate status penamt trnamt extraamt
5140560000001183    1016.00     0.00    2014-05-23  R       0.00    1017    13
5140560000001191    880.00      0.00    2014-05-23  R       0.00    880     0
5140560000001142    934.00      0.00    2014-05-23  P       0.00    500     0
5140560000001209    963.00      0.00    2014-05-23  P       0.00    600     0
5140560000001175    1024.00     0.00    2014-05-23  N       0.00    0       0
5140560000001167    1117.00     0.00    2014-05-23  N       0.00    0       0
5140560000001159    834.00      0.00    2014-05-23  N       0.00    0       0
5140560000001183    1016.00     0.00    2014-05-24  N       30.00   1017    0
5140560000001191    880.00      0.00    2014-05-24  N       0.00    880     0
5140560000001142    934.00      0.00    2014-05-24  N       0.00    500     0
5140560000001209    963.00      0.00    2014-05-24  N       0.00    600     0
5140560000001175    1024.00     0.00    2014-05-24  N       0.00    0       0
5140560000001167    1117.00     0.00    2014-05-24  N       0.00    0       0
5140560000001159    834.00      0.00    2014-05-24  N       0.00    0       0
```

I have used the below query but still it is not helping:

```
 Select
 Case WHEN ( lastrecdate=( cast (GETDATE() as DATE))and CardNo=CardNo and Status in('N','P') ) then trnammt else 0 end +
 Case WHEN ( lastrecdate=( cast (GETDATE() as DATE))and CardNo=CardNo and Status in('N','P')) then pendamt else 0 end +
 Case WHEN (lastrecdate= (select MAX(lastrecdate ) from Tbl_Emi WHERE Status ='R' and CardNo=CardNo)  ) then extraamt  else 0 end  as totalamount
 from Tbl_Emi where  CardNo=CardNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Please google on **CrossTab query/Pivot Query**. You can achieve this task using this.
**CrossTab query** is amazing, which helps generating reports and play with aggregate values. Excel/Ms Access gives nice user interface for Pivot Table. It’s way to transfer rows into column. It is more often used to generate matrix form of report.
Look at [this blog](http://www.krishnasunuwar.com.np/2011/02/crosstab-query-pivot-table-or-transformation-of-rows-into-columns/).

Comment: I checked the crpssTab query, but it something new to me, may you can provide me of how to use my query using the crosstab query

Comment: please specify your expected output and table structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
select tt.carno, t1.extraamt+t2.trnamt total from

(select t.carno,
MIN(t.lastrecdate) first
,  MAX(t.lastrecdate) second

from dbo.[Table] t 
group by t.carno) tt
inner join dbo.[Table] t1
 on t1.carno=tt.carno and t1.lastrecdate=tt.first
inner join dbo.[Table] t2 
  on t2.carno=tt.carno and t2.lastrecdate=tt.second
```